# Datepicker - Won't attach to Dynamic element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

**I am aware this question has been asked and answered on SO before, however those solutions have not had success in getting this to work or i have missed the one that would work**

**index.php**

```
<id="fupdiv"></div>
<input name="non-dynamic-test-element" type="text" class="datepicker">
<button id="addticket">Open Dynamic Form</button>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
$(document).on('click','#addticket', function() {
    $("#fupdiv").load('blocks/form-followup.php');
    $("#fupdiv").fadeIn();
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("refresh");
                                                });
});
```

**form-followup.php**

```
<div>
<label> Should get datepicker on click</label> <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dynamic-input">
</div>
```

**Question:**
Clicking on the "non-dynamic-test-element" input opens DatePicker properly. Clicking on the loaded "dynamic-element" input does not, no errors are thrown in console and I have tried several different ways to attach datepicker to the dynamic element. As I understand it, using the .on() method and binding datepicker AFTER the load should work? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX calls are asynchronous, so the refresh can be executed before the elements are placed in DOM, hence no binding. So the binding should be refreshed in the load callback.

```
$("#fupdiv").load('blocks/form-followup.php',function(){
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I made that change to the code and had no change occur. No errors, but no Datepicker on the dynamic load either.

Comment: @DMSJax can you try just `$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();` inside the function?

Comment: Thanks that Worked!! Dropping the refresh did the trick. Refresh was a leftover of one of the other SO answers, Thanks !   Edit your answer to drop the refresh and i'll accept it.